# Make wordpress post title containing id for a new post created with wp_insert_post()

Tags: wordpress

i create some new post in wp with this part of code:

```
 $wordpress_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Preorder №',
    'post_content' => 'Post Content',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'preorders'
    );
 
    wp_insert_post( $wordpress_post );
```

As you can see, i have 'Preorder №' in post_title, so my goal is to make it like 'Preorder № 4522', where 4522 is the id of this newly created post. How can i do it with standart wp stuff?

Comment: The ID will only be generated the moment the new post is actually getting stored into the database - so it does not exist at the point where you call `wp_insert_post` there. But - `wp_insert_post` will return the post ID on success, and if you _pass_ it a post ID in the post data, it will _update_ that existing post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post id does not exist before you actually created the post, so there's no other option than to first create and then update the post:

```
$wordpress_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Preorder №',
    'post_content' => 'Post Content',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'preorders'
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $wordpress_post );

$wordpress_post['ID'] = $post_id;
$wordpress_post['post_title'] = 'Preorder № ' . $post_id;

wp_insert_post( $wordpress_post );
```

It might be easier, however, to not store the id inside the title and concatenate title and id when retrieving the posts.

Comment: Thanks, man, but maybe last string is ```wp_update_post( $post_data );``` ?

Comment: As long as the key 'ID' is present and its value is something other than 0, the post with the given ID will be updated not inserted. The description of the function wp_insert_post is "Inserts or update a post."

Comment: I've updated to code to actually extend the original array instead of creating a new one. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks man, it really works. I little modified the code according to my purposes, but in general the idea is right - wp_insert_post() can also update the post, so problem solved.